# MYSQL Query within Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, mysql2

Need to update a field within my mysql db. Would like to use the following query within rails:

```
update users set exported = TRUE where id = #{name[12]}
```

Currently, have the following:

```
db = Mysql2::Client.new( :host => 'localhost', :username => 'username', :password => 'password', :database => 'database')

results = db.query("select * from users where start_date is not NULL AND exported = 0").each(:as => :array)

results.each do |name|

db.query("update users set exported = TRUE where id = #{name[12]}")

end
```

index 12 is equal to the UID.

Comment: Are you aware of the Active Record existence in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use [`ActiveRecord`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) for database calls when you are using Ruby on Rails.

I assume that you have at least a basic `User` model like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

With an `User` model like that your query could look like this:

```
User.where.not(start_date: nil).where(exported: false).update_all(exported: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails, I'd suggest using [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html). Your update will be:

```
@users = User.find(:all, :where => 'start_date is not null and exported = 0 and id = ?', name[12])
@users.each{ |user|
    user.exported = true
    user.save!
}
```

Hope that helps! Leave a comment if you need further help.

Comment: That `find(:all)` seems a bit old. `User.where('start_date != NULL AND exported = 0 AND id = ?', name[12]).update_all(exported: true)` should work at least for Rails 4+.

Comment: True, OP didn't indicate what version he was using. That query works in console.

Comment: `find(:all)` is deprecated since Rails 3.2. I doubt that the OP is using such an old version of Rails.

Comment: Question: Can we still use activerecord even if we output data to an external mysql db?

Comment: @Arjae_t this is a separate question. If you create a chat with me, I'll look into it. Alternatively, ask a new question. It looks as though there is an [establish_connection](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling/establish_connection) method. This should get you started.